# Unable to link a function defined in .cu file when being called from a .cpp file

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker

I have the following directory structure

```
Project
   * main.cpp
   * kernels.cu
   * kernel.hpp
   * CMakeLists.txt
```

The contents of the files are as follows
CMakeLists.txt -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(cudaTest CUDA CXX)


find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(exe kernels.cu kernels.hpp main.cpp)
set_target_properties(exe PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "75")

target_link_libraries(exe CUDA::cudart ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "kernels.hpp"

int main()
{
    float* a, *b, *c;

    cudaMalloc(&a, 1024 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&b, 1024 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&c, 1024 * sizeof(float));

    auto func = getAddKernel();

    launchKernel<decltype(func)>(func, c, a, b, 1024, getDim(1), getDim(1024));
}
```

kernels.hpp

```
#ifndef KERNELS_HPP
#define KERNELS_HPP

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include <iostream>

__global__ void addKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, size_t n);

auto getAddKernel(void){return addKernel;}

dim3 getDim(int x, int y, int z){return dim3(x, y, z);}
dim3 getDim(int x, int y){return dim3(x, y);}
dim3 getDim(int x){return dim3(x);}

template<typename Kernel>
int launchKernel(Kernel K, float* c, float* b, float* a, size_t n, dim3 gridDim, dim3 blockDim);

#endif /*!KERNELS_HPP*/
```

and finally kernels.cu

```
#include "kernels.hpp"

__global__ void addKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, size_t n)
{
    auto idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(idx < n)
        c[idx] = a[idx] * b[idx];
}

template<typename Kernel>
void launchKernel(Kernel K, float* c, float* b, float* a, size_t n, dim3 gridDim, dim3 blockDim)
{
    K<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(a, b, c, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Upon compilation, I have two types of error, One of multiple definitions, who's excerpt is as follows -

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getAddKernel()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `getAddKernel()'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_00014424_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1a): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): multiple definition of `getDim(int, int, int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_00014424_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2b): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78): multiple definition of `getDim(int, int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_00014424_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x92): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xde): multiple definition of `getDim(int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_00014424_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xf8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
```

and an undefined reference for the function `launchKernel`, and the error is as follows -

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `int launchKernel<void (*)(float*, float*, float*, unsigned long)>(void (*)(float*, float*, float*, unsigned long), float*, float*, float*, unsigned long, dim3, dim3)'
```

My Questions are as follows -

- Even though I have included a header guard, why do I get the multiple definitions error, I believe I have not completely understood how the header guard works.
- How do I resolve the undefined reference error.

TIA

Edit - Updating the question with entire error -

```
atharva@dubey:~/CPP_Projects/opencvTest/__bld$ make clean all
[ 33%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable exe
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getAddKernel()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `getAddKernel()'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_0001565f_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1a): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): multiple definition of `getDim(int, int, int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_0001565f_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2b): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78): multiple definition of `getDim(int, int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_0001565f_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x92): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `getDim(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xde): multiple definition of `getDim(int)'; CMakeFiles/exe.dir/kernels.cu.o:tmpxft_0001565f_00000000-6_kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xf8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `int launchKernel<void (*)(float*, float*, float*, unsigned long)>(void (*)(float*, float*, float*, unsigned long), float*, float*, float*, unsigned long, dim3, dim3)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/exe.dir/build.make:182: exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: I don’t believe the code you have shown is actually the code producing the errors you have shown.  If you really import kernels.hpp into your C++ main you should get a syntax error during compilation and you build should get nowhere near the linker

Comment: @talonmies, this is the entirety of the code, I will update the question with the entire error. In case it makes any difference, GCC version is 11.2 and nvcc is at 11.7. BTW, where do you see a syntax error ?

Comment: You have CUDA syntax in kernels.hpp. If you include that into a file compiled by a C++ compiler, it will fail with a syntax error

Comment: oh, the `__global__` part ? .. I thought it was alright if we included headers. in any case, it is not throwing that error as of now. BTW, could you tell what would be the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: From inspection only (a) Don't put definitions in headers (you are compiling them twice and no the preprocess guard doesn't help), (b) You must instantiate templates at the scope of translation unit where they are defined, (c) don't pass non C++ language features to C++ compilers

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing a `static` keyword in the functions defined in your headers. This is required for all C/C++ non-templated functions in order to limit the visibility of this function to the current compilation unit, and avoid conflicts with the same function included from other compilation units. Example below:

```cpp
#ifndef KERNELS_HPP
#define KERNELS_HPP

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include <iostream>

__global__ void addKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, size_t n);

static auto getAddKernel(void){return addKernel;}

static dim3 getDim(int x, int y, int z){return dim3(x, y, z);}
static dim3 getDim(int x, int y){return dim3(x, y);}
static dim3 getDim(int x){return dim3(x);}

template<typename Kernel>
static int launchKernel(Kernel K, float* c, float* b, float* a, size_t n, dim3 gridDim, dim3 blockDim);

#endif /*!KERNELS_HPP*/
```

For more information on linkages, you can check the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage) page on the subject.